# Change LineRenderer draw order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written the below script which create line LineRenderer objects and emulates a basic 'painting' ability within Unity3d. This works pretty well however I can't seem to get it to render the lines on top of each other correctly. It seems random as to which will appear at the front and which will go to the back.

For example:

[image: Example]

In this image the lines where drawn in the order Black, Orange, Blue, Yellow, Red, Green. However as you can see this is not the order they have been rendered.

```
void Update ()
    {
        //Create new Line on left mouse click(down)
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            prevPos     = Input.mousePosition;
            points = 2;
            //check if there is no line renderer created
            if(line == null){
                //create the line
                createLine();
            }
            //get the mouse position
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x,
                Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

            //set the start point and end point of the line renderer
            line.SetPosition(0,mousePos);
            line.SetPosition(1,mousePos);
        }
        //if line renderer exists and left mouse button is click exited (up)
        else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") && line)
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x,
                Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
            //set the end point of the line renderer to current mouse position
            line.SetPosition(points-1,mousePos);
            //set line as null once the line is created
            line = null;
            currLines++;
        }
        //if mouse button is held clicked and line exists
        else if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")  && line)
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x,
                Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
            //set the end position as current position but dont set line as null as the mouse click is not exited
            line.SetPosition(points-1, mousePos);

            currPos = Input.mousePosition;
            if (currPos != prevPos) {
                prevPos = currPos;
                points = points + 1;
                line.SetVertexCount (points);
                line.SetPosition(points-1, mousePos);
            }

        }

        if (clearing) {
            GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("lines");

            for(var i = 0 ; i < gameObjects.Length ; i ++)
            {
                Destroy(gameObjects[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    //method to create line
    private void createLine()
    {
        Material newm = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Color")); 
        newm.SetColor("_Color", lineColor);
        //create a new empty gameobject and line renderer component
        line = new GameObject("Line"+currLines).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.tag = "lines";
        //assign the material to the line
        line.material =  newm;
        //set the number of points to the line
        line.SetVertexCount(2);

        //set the width
        line.SetWidth(((float)lineSize)/1000, ((float)lineSize)/1000);
        //render line to the world origin and not to the object's position
        line.useWorldSpace = true;  

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *"Sorting Layer"* and *"Order In Layer"* properties to do this. *"Order In Layer"* is recommended for this since all you need are just int values to change them. Only use  *"Sorting Layer"* if necessary. The `LineRenderer` with the highest *"Order In Layer"* value will be drawn on top of other `LineRenderers`.

Changing *"Order In Layer"* via script:

Your four lines:

```
public LineRenderer line1;
public LineRenderer line2;
public LineRenderer line3;
public LineRenderer line4;
```

Arrange them on the screen:

```
line1.sortingOrder = 3;
line2.sortingOrder = 2;
line3.sortingOrder = 1;
line4.sortingOrder = 0;
```

This means that *line 1* will be placed on top of all the other lines, followed by *line 2*, then *line 3* and finally *line 4*. So, *line 4* will be placed beneath all the lines. *This is the proper way to do this and it will work with both 2D and 3D vector positions.*

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are drawing the line renderer on **XY** plane. Then **Z** will denote the **depth** of the line renderer. Take a depth variable in script of type int. Whenever a line is drawn increase this by 1. Whenever, you are drawing the line, set it's **points** Z according to the depth. You can do that during the **SetPosition** function call. Hope this makes sense.